# How to remove spacing between bars of same group in ssrs?

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am not able to find any option by which I can remove spacing between bars of same group/category in SSRS. Please help

[Current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOYFy.png)

[Output Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otxgq.png)

Comment: Maybe attached a screenshot of what it looks like at the moment and what you want it to look like? Not sure what bars you are referring to

Comment: Ok that's easier to understand. What I would do is make the bottom axis use all available months not just the ones that have data. (in your dataset maybe you could return a 0 value for each month if there is nothing). Then put a formula in the text colour of the bottom axis headers to be white if the value is 0

Comment: Some how logic for header font colour change is not working I have used this logic IIf(Fields!TEAM.Value="Team0","White","Black")